# Flexbox image does not accept max-height

Tags: css, image, height, size, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/qn6vcbvy/1/

**Problem**

I have an image that is too large for the container. In "normal" cases the image would respect the max-height value. In this case I use flexbox and it does not listen to the max-height value.

The result should be that the image will fit the black area perfectly when the image is larger than the container.

I know it would be possible to use a background for it. If it's possible with the image element it will get my vote.

**Why I'm using max-height and not height**

Max-height will only set the height value when necessary needed, to prevent the image to overflow the container.

If the container is larger than the image, the height will then fallback on the height of the image.

That's why max-height is used.

**html**

```
<div class="modal-window">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.modal-window {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.image img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your css from this :

```
.image {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

to this :

```
.image {
  height: inherit;
}
```

the value `inherit` just takes the value from its parent.

Comment: Yes, I can use height, but I want to use max-height because it should be aware of the image height when scaling the container. In other words, the image should be shrinked when the container is small. The image should never be larger than the maximum height of the image.

Comment: It is what you are looking for because your just tellin the container around  the image to have the same size as its parent. The image itself will not go over its original size.

Comment: Fair enough. I added information of why I'm using max-height and not height in my post.

Comment: Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn6vcbvy/2/) just change the height of yout modal window and you see that it is working.